# The Firebase function doesn't work for Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Hope you are well.
I have a problem with my Arduino code.
I have `LED_Function()` which is working fine, what I want, when I send “ON” from the firebase the `LED_Function()` is stop working and execute the `(DeviceStatus.stringData() == "ON")` conditions (continuous working till I send OFF). When I send “OFF”, `LED_Function()` is stop working and the code execute `(DeviceStatus.stringData() == "OFF")` conditions. If I didn’t send anything, the `LED_Function()` is working continuously. Please, I appreciate if you could help me in this matter.

```
void loop() {
LED_Function();

Firebase.getString(DeviceStatus, "LED_STATUS/LED");
Serial.print("The signal is:  ");
Serial.println(DeviceStatus.stringData());

if (DeviceStatus.stringData() == "ON") {
Firebase.setFloat(DeviceStatus, "LED_STATUS/LED", 55);
digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led, LOW);
Serial.println("Led Turned ON");

}
if (DeviceStatus.stringData() == "OFF") {
Firebase.setFloat(DeviceStatus, "LED_STATUS/LED", 55);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
Serial.println("Led Turned OFF");

}
}


void LED_Function() {

int Detect = analogRead(SensorRec);

if (isnan(Detect)) {
Serial.println(F("Failed to read from Laser sensor!"));
return;
}


if (Detect < 300) {
Serial.println("Laser Cut. Data is disptched to the Firebase!");

digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
digitalWrite(led7, LOW);
float  val = 1.0;
Serial.println(val);
}

else {
float   val = 2.0;
digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led7, HIGH);
Serial.println(val);

}
}
```

Thanks in advance........

Comment: you should add information on how the behaviour of  your code differs from what you step. please note that "doesn't work" is not very useful. also note that this is C++, not C. please read [ask]

Comment: Is `stringData` a `std::string` or a `char*`? You've tagged this C for some reason, yet this code will most definitely break in C. Unless you are using C++ strings, none of it makes sense.

Comment: The code is working fine, however, the condition is not working probably. Coz LED_Function () is working with the ON/OFF message simultaneously. The code is in C Language and I have implemented it in Arduino IDE.

Comment: As the others stated, it's C++, not C. What type does `DeviceStatus.stringData()` return?